# does boost-1.55 boost::property_tree::ptree compile with c++11?

Tags: c++11, boost

I'm trying to compile the following source code

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::property_tree::ptree b;
    b.push_back(std::make_pair("a", "b"));

    return 9;
}
```

using the following compiler and instructions:

```
$ g++ ./source.cpp --std=c++11
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ # boost version is 1.55
```

and I'm getting the following error

```
./source.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./source.cpp:5:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >::push_back(std::pair<const char*, const char*>)’
     b.push_back(std::make_pair("a", "b"));
                                     ^
In file included from /opt/boost/boost_1_55_0/boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp:516:0,
                 from ./source.cpp:1:
/opt/boost/boost_1_55_0/boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp:362:9: note: candidate: boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<Key, Data, KeyCompare>::iterator boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<Key, Data, KeyCompare>::push_back(const value_type&) [with Key = std::basic_string<char>; Data = std::basic_string<char>; KeyCompare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >; boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<Key, Data, KeyCompare>::value_type = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >]
         basic_ptree<K, D, C>::push_back(const value_type &value)
         ^
/opt/boost/boost_1_55_0/boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp:362:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::pair<const char*, const char*>’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >&}’
```

NOTE: if I'm compiling this without --std=c++11 the error disappears

QUESTION: how may I compile it using c++11 standard or higher? I've found https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/6785 , but in boost-1.55 it has been already fixed. thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. The real change here is `std::make_pair`.

C++11 changed `std::pair` conversion rules, as well as the `make_pair` convenience function, which was made move-aware.

### Analyzing It

Property Tree allows construction like this:

```
ptree pt("data");
```

to construct a tree with only value data and no child nodes. However, the indirect conversion for the `second` member of the pair doesn't apply in c++11 mode:

```
std::pair<std::string, ptree> v = std::make_pair("a", "b");
```

This line would have compiled in c++03, but no longer compiles in c++11

### Isolating It

To find out whether it might be a libstdc++ or compiler bug, I isolated it into this minimal sample:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>

struct X {
    X(std::string){}
};

int main() {
    std::pair<std::string, X> v = std::make_pair("a", "b");
}
```

> **Note** the subtle point that it doesn't matter that the constructor isn't `explicit` like with the `ptree(data_type const&)` constructor. The additional implicit conversion `char const(&)[] -> std::string` required is enough to cause c++11 to reject the call.

This [compiles in c++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0b00dbbd1a9ad26) but [fails in c++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7c390f8ef6b18d8) under GCC with libstdc++.

Just to check, [clang agrees](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91813a7b074203eb) even when using [libc++ instead of libstdc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/887835e59a7149d6).

> At I bet this is by design and probably a result of making `std::make_pair` more precise and aware of move-semantics.

### How To Fix

The workarounds are manifold. Convert explicitly:

```
b.push_back(std::make_pair("a", ptree("b")));
```

Making types explicit always helps:

```
b.push_back(ptree::value_type {"a", "b"});
```

Uniform initialization removes some cruft:

```
b.push_back({"a", ptree{"b"}});
```

For completeness, non-explicit constructors are more flexible:

```
b.push_back({"a", {}});
```

---

Or you can **avoid the `pair<>` (`value_type`) interface altogether**:

```
b.add_child("a", ptree{"b"});
b.add_child("a", {}).put_value("b");
```

But the real key here is that *value nodes cannot have children*. Why not just *put the value*?

```
b.add("a", "b");
```

> This is my **RECOMMENDATION**. I feel `std::pair<>` is an implementation detail only useful to interoperate with other generic code. It hurts readability.

### Live Demo

All the workarounds happily living together **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85b9ae4ca6aa4b6c)</kbd>**

Prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a>b</a>
<a>b</a>
<a>b</a>
<a/>
<a>b</a>
<a>b</a>
<a>b</a>
```

Comment: If you have time for an excellent talk, listen to Stephan Lavavej explain why doing `std::make_pair<std::string, ptree>` is ***not*** the solution you want to do ["Don't Help The Compiler" 48:42](https://youtu.be/AKtHxKJRwp4?t=2922). He also explains some of the changes to `std::pair` and `std::make_pair` in c++11