# Compile error boost property tree c++

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile with boost property tree for a custom linux. I have an error on the file json_parser_read.hpp (line 105)

```
struct a_literal_val
    {
        context &c;
        a_literal_val(context &c): c(c) { }
        void operator()(It b, It e) const
        {
            BOOST_ASSERT(c.stack.size() >= 1);
            c.stack.back()->push_back(std::make_pair(c.name, Str(b, e)));
            c.name.clear();
            c.string.clear();
        }
    };
```

This piece of code does not compile.
Output is : `/path/to/boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_read.hpp:105: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >::push_back(std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >)'
                 c.stack.back()->push_back(std::make_pair(c.name, Str(b, e)));
                 ^`

I'm using boost v1.49

I tested with other pc and it compiles correctly with version 1.58

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What is `context`? What is `c.stack`? What is returned by `c.stack.back()`? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And of course please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the SSCCE you should have created. I can't see your problem¹,²:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/006fa2aceee51a9b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <deque>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;

struct context {
    std::string name, string;
    std::deque<ptree *> stack;
};

struct a_literal_val {
    using Str = std::string;

    context &c;
    a_literal_val(context &c) : c(c) {}

    template <typename It>
    void operator()(It b, It e) const {
        BOOST_ASSERT(c.stack.size() >= 1);
        c.stack.back()->push_back(std::make_pair(c.name, ptree{Str(b, e)}));
        c.name.clear();
        c.string.clear();
    }
};

#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    context ctx { "field1", "", { &pt } };

    a_literal_val visitor {ctx};

    std::string const value = "hello world";
    visitor(value.rbegin(), value.rend()); // reverse, for fun

    write_json(std::cout, pt);
}
```

Prints

```
{
    "field1": "dlrow olleh"
}
```

---

¹ except that you're likely abusing Boost Property as an XML or JSON library. Boost ***does not have*** an XML or a JSON library.

² yes I know your sample is more complicated. Most likely you're writing a "generic" serializer for your interface code. And even deeper in my crystal ball I can guess that you're using Boost Fusion adapted structs in order to process nested object graphs. It's all been done before. The point is, you need to present the problem you have, or nobody will know.

Comment: By the way, I just realized this change is your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47213341/85371