# Recursive pair via boost.Variant broken since boost 1.62

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

The code I'm working on uses a recursive pair. In the simplified example the type holds a pair consisting of a `string` and either an `int` or another such pair. This should (and was) achievable with this:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::make_recursive_variant
      < std::pair
        < std::string
        , boost::variant<int, boost::recursive_variant_>
        >
      >::type recursivePair;

typedef boost::variant< int
                    , recursivePair
                    > intPairVariant;

using sType = boost::variant<pair<string, string>, int>;

void foo(){
    sType bar(make_pair("aa", "bb"));
    recursivePair xxx(std::make_pair (std::string("s"), intPairVariant()));
    recursivePair yyy(std::make_pair (string("s"), 5));
    recursivePair zzz(std::make_pair ("s", 5));
}
```

The `sType` is to show that implicit conversions in the pair still apply.

However starting with Boost 1.62 this breaks during compilation:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::variant<boost::detail::variant::recursive_flag<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::variant<int, boost::recursive_variant_> > > >::variant(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)’
     recursivePair yyy(std::make_pair (string("s"), 5));
```

This is for one type only. The others fail similarly.

Does anyone know why this does not work anymore and how to fix this?

Comment: The changes to Boost Variant are listed in the release notes http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_62_0.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're actually running into a similar change to `std::pair<>` seen here: [does boost-1.55 boost::property_tree::ptree compile with c++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213341/does-boost-1-55-boostproperty-treeptree-compile-with-c11/47220315#47220315)

There are fewer implicit conversions for std::pair since c++11. It is true that your code *did* compile boost < 1.62 but, in essence it looks like that was a mistake, at least in c++11 mode.

In C++11, you are doing this:

```
std::make_pair(s, i); // s is std::string, i is int
```

which results in `std::pair<std::string, int>`. Next you're not only asking an implicit conversion of `std::pair<std::string, int>` to `std::pair<std::string, IntPairVariant>`, but you're expecting to use the *result of that conversion* as the initializer for the variant you're assigning.

In all parts of C++, that's asking for two implicit conversions and the compiler would never resolve an overload using that.

So, in effect your code was bit sloppy in that it used "leeway" that Boost Variant should likely not not have had. It **is** a breaking change, but the new behaviour seems to make more sense.

### Another note

You're making a recursive variant with a single element. That's... a bit weird.

This "strains" the type system a bit more than necessary by hiding the `std::pair<>` structural property under the first layer of `variant`.

### Using A `std::pair` directly

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4cef9b5e20148e3)</kbd>**

The most boring thing I can imagine:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef std::pair<std::string,
    boost::make_recursive_variant<int, std::pair<std::string, boost::recursive_variant_> >::type >
    recursivePair;

typedef boost::variant<int, recursivePair> intPairVariant;

int main() {
    recursivePair xxx(std::string("s"), intPairVariant());
    recursivePair yyy(string("s"), 5);
    recursivePair zzz("s", 5);
}
```

Note this already allows the exact spellings in your question:

```
recursivePair xxx(std::make_pair(std::string("s"), intPairVariant()));
recursivePair yyy(std::make_pair(string("s"), 5));
recursivePair zzz(std::make_pair("s", 5));
```

But `make_pair` is redundant in all three cases.

### Interesting Variations

Perhaps you can do something more like

```
struct V;
using Pair = std::pair<std::string, V>;

struct V : boost::variant<int, boost::recursive_wrapper<Pair> > {
    using base = boost::variant<int, boost::recursive_wrapper<Pair> >;
    using base::base;
    using base::operator=;
};
```

Now you can safely say

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/393861f1f870372e)</kbd>**

```
Pair xxx("s", V{});
Pair yyy("s", 5);
Pair zzz{};
```

### Helping The Constructor

The upside of having the derived struct instead of a plain variant is that you can actually disambiguate constructors:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bc13389c9397b8e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace mylib {

    struct V;
    using Pair = std::pair<std::string, V>;

    struct V : boost::variant<int, boost::recursive_wrapper<Pair> > {
        using base = boost::variant<int, boost::recursive_wrapper<Pair> >;

        V() = default;
        V(V&&) = default;
        V(V const&) = default;
        V& operator=(V&&) = default;
        V& operator=(V const&) = default;

        V(int i) : base(i) {}
        V(std::string const& key, V value);
    };

    V::V(std::string const& key, V value) : base{Pair{std::move(key), std::move(value)}} {}

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Pair const& p) {
        return os << "{" << p.first << "," << p.second << "}";
    }
}

int main() {
    using mylib::V;
    V xxx("s", mylib::V{});
    V yyy("s", 5);
    V zzz{};
    V huh("s", {"more", {"intricate", {"nested", { "truths", 42} } } });

    V simple = 5;
    simple = {"simple", 5};
    simple = {"not_so_simple", simple};

    std::cout << "xxx:" << xxx << "\n";
    std::cout << "yyy:" << yyy << "\n";
    std::cout << "zzz:" << zzz << "\n";
    std::cout << "huh:" << huh << "\n";
    std::cout << "simple:" << simple << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
xxx:{s,0}
yyy:{s,5}
zzz:0
huh:{s,{more,{intricate,{nested,{truths,42}}}}}
simple:{not_so_simple,{simple,5}}
```

Comment: Came up late with the most ["boring" variation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4cef9b5e20148e3) that directly [solves your issue](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db0eb2b70f1b4327).

Comment: There is an even better (not so) "boring" solution which has less duplication: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c15b161a6a5c60d5

I found this while evaluating your solution and applying it to "the real thing". This is simply based on "what do I want?" (Hence the comment)   
Before I can accept your answer: Your First variation fails on clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27f4a44d2ceea49c Besides that I like it better due to less duplication on the real thing. And while your "ctor help" seems nice, I'd expect it not be required.

Comment: Oh, it seems to be a bug in clang 3.8 which is solved in clang 3.9: https://godbolt.org/g/7NiGQB